# Empty text validation on multiple textfields inside alert controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

[image: uialert controller]

This is my ui alert controller. I need to have the submit button disabled if any of the text fields are empty. Currently I have a method to validate a single text field, but I cant seem to figure out how to apply it to all of them. This is my alert controller and text fields:

```
  let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Enter Custom Specifications", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    ac.addTextField { (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "Material Name"
        textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
    }

    ac.addTextField { (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = ""
        textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.decimalPad
    }

    ac.addTextField { (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = ""
        textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.decimalPad
    }

    ac.addTextField { (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = ""
        textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.decimalPad
    }
```

Using this function called in the first textfield above I can get proper empty string validation per textfield, meaning submit is disabled while that first textfield is empty but then submit becomes enabled when I start typing. If I put the function call in each textfield declaration, the same behavior is present for each one.

```
 @objc func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField){
    if textField.text == "" {

        submitAction.isEnabled = false
    }
    else
    {
        submitAction.isEnabled = true

    }

}
```

I need a way to check all textfields at the same time and have submit disabled if any of them are empty.

EDIT:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField.text == "" {
        //You can perfrom your activity here when textfield got blank or empty
        submitAction.isEnabled = false
    }
    else if textField.text != ""
    {
        submitAction.isEnabled = true
        //You can perfrom your activity here when textfield got not blank or not empty
    }
    //add your code here...
    return true
}
```

EDIT2:

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

```
    if let text = (textField.text as? NSString)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string), !text.isEmpty {
        if let text = textField.text?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string), !text.isEmpty {
            submitAction.isEnabled = true
        } else {
            submitAction.isEnabled = false
        }
        return true
    }}
```

EDIT 3:
Instead of all the textfields just being called "textfield" I can name them textfield"x" when I create them:

```
ac.addTextField { (textField2 : UITextField!) -> Void in
        textField2.placeholder = "Column Width (in)"
        textField2.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.decimalPad
        textField2.delegate = self
    }
```

How can I get shouldChangeCharactersIn to accept them all at the same time?

EDIT (solution):

Ok I figured it out. PGDev was correct on the logic part of it but not the delegate function used to actually check. I'm going to mark his answer correct since I wouldn't have gotten to this point without it.

Initially we were using textFieldDidEndEditing, and I thought it just simply wasn't working because it wouldn't reenable the submit button once all four text fields were filled. What I didn't realize is that I had to tap an additional textfield after I was done for textFieldDidEndEditing to be called. Makes sense since it has "EndEditing" in the name.

I took PGDevs logic and put it in shouldChangeCharactersIn which worked but not perfectly. I'm not sure if there's an internal issue with it but when you try to fill the last text box sometimes backspace (or something) is interpreted as a character and it throws the enable / !enable statement out of wack.

textFieldDidChange using PGDevs logic was the answer.

set class wide variables for how many text boxes you're going to add to your alert controller:

```
var textField1: UITextField?
var textField2: UITextField?
var textField3: UITextField?
var textField4: UITextField?
```

Put this function at the bottom of your class function:

```
   @objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {

    let text1 = self.textField1?.text ?? ""
    let text2 = self.textField2?.text ?? ""
    let text3 = self.textField3?.text ?? ""
    let text4 = self.textField4?.text ?? ""

    if !text1.isEmpty && !text2.isEmpty && !text3.isEmpty && !text4.isEmpty {
        submitAction.isEnabled = true
    } else {
        submitAction.isEnabled = false
    }

}
```

When you generate an actual text field in the alert controller, call the above function:

```
 let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Enter Custom Specifications", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    ac.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    ac.addTextField { (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
        textField.delegate = self
        textField.placeholder = "Material Name"
        self.textField1 = textField
        textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    }
```

This works perfectly for me. unless all 4 rows have at least one character in them, submit stays disabled. This could be used for as many text fields as you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the delegate of each textField as the viewCobtroller where you're presenting the alert, i.e.

```
textField.delegate = self
```

Conform the ViewController to UITextFieldDelegate protocol,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
```

Implemennt the relevant `UITextFieldDelegate` methods, Example:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if let text = (textField.text as? NSString)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string), !text.isEmpty {
        submitAction.isEnabled = true
    } else {
        submitAction.isEnabled = false
    }
    return true
}
```

**Edit:**

You need to keep the `reference` to all the `textFields` so you can check the `text` in all of them to `enable/disable` the `submitAction`, i.e.

```
var textField1: UITextField?
var textField2: UITextField?
var textField3: UITextField?
var textField4: UITextField?
```

Set each of the `textFields` while adding to the `UIAlertController`, i.e.

```
let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Enter Custom Specifications", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
ac.addTextField { (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
    textField.delegate = self
    textField.placeholder = "Material Name"
    self.textField1 = textField
}
ac.addTextField { (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
    textField.delegate = self
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.decimalPad
    self.textField2 = textField
}
ac.addTextField { (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
    textField.delegate = self
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.decimalPad
    self.textField3 = textField
}
ac.addTextField { (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
    textField.delegate = self
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.decimalPad
    self.textField4 = textField
}
```

Call `validate()` everytime there is a change in any of the `textFields`, i.e.

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    self.validate()
}


func validate() {
    let text1 = self.textField1?.text ?? ""
    let text2 = self.textField2?.text ?? ""
    let text3 = self.textField3?.text ?? ""
    let text4 = self.textField4?.text ?? ""

    if !text1.isEmpty && !text2.isEmpty && !text3.isEmpty && !text4.isEmpty {
        submitAction.isEnabled = true
    } else {
        submitAction.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I implement your suggestion submit is disabled if a single character is entered per line, otherwise its enabled. I don't understand why though. I added my basic logic to the delegate function you suggested, please see edit.

Comment: Edited the answer. You need to check the final string created in `textField`. `textField.text` in `shouldChangeCharactersIn` method gives the string before editing.

Comment: Thank you, I get this error: "Argument type 'NSRange' (aka '_NSRange') does not conform to expected type 'RangeExpression'"  on "range" in "textField.text?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string), !text.isEmpty"

Comment: Which Swift version are you using?

Comment: Updated the code. Simply typecast it to `NSString`.

Comment: Sorry. I updated my code with your update and still getting this error: "Argument type 'NSRange' (aka '_NSRange') does not conform to expected type 'RangeExpression'" I'm using swift 4, Xcode 10.2.1

Comment: Add the exact code for method `shouldChangeCharactersIn` so I can have a look.

Comment: I couldn't see the EDIT2 in your question.

Comment: Just copy and paste the exact code along with method signature in your file and see if you still face the issue,

Comment: Whoops i added edit2 to the wrong place, its now in the original question. What is the method signature exactly?

Comment: The Edit-2 is wrong. Copy and paste it from my answer and then check.

Comment: ok i copied from your answer and there aren't any errors so i was able to run it. Each text field when active disables the submit button and as soon as i start typing the button is enabled, however this behavior is unaffected by other textfields contents. If i type in the first text box then submit is enabled even when all the other text fields are empty.

Comment: You need to build a logic for that which check the value of each textField.

Comment: I added what I think I should do to the original question in the form of edit3, but I'm not sure how to have shouldChangeCharactersIn accept all the textfields at the same time.

Comment: Updated the answer. I think this will resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you for this, unfortunately it leaves submit permanently disabled.

Comment: See, you need to give a try for whatever logic you want to build. We can only help you achieve that instead of writing the whole code for you.

Comment: I know what you mean! I've been constantly trying to get this working. I was close with making global variables and trying to reference the textfields on the alert controller but didn't quite get as far as you did. To me it seems like your solution should work though. Validate is constantly checking if all four are empty, and if they aren't then submit should be enabled. I don't understand why it's not.